# Define source code encoding on command line, not in source code

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

I want to contribute to an open source python library which is on 2.7. (https://github.com/plexinc-plugins) Its source code files do *not* have this `coding: utf-8` header comment that everywhere is mentioned and apparently was set in [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). However, I still get an `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file […] but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details` when I try to `$ python` them on the command line.

(How) can I set on interpreter level, i.e. with the `python` command, that the whole code base is UTF-8?

What I tried:

- I've seen environment variables (`PYTHONUTF8=1` or `PYTHONIOENCODING`) that are supposed to do the trick but they don't work, i.e. error stays the same. (aha: seems to be >=3.7, so nevermind)
- A command-line argument `-X utf8` says `-X is reserved for implementation-specific arguments`. (dito 3.7)
- There's also stuff going on with a `sitecustomize.py` but I don't know what it is. Is it a bootstrap file that is loaded prior to everything else? At least I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: What library? What environment variables?

Comment: `PYTHONIOENCODING` is for io encoding, it's not related to source code encoding.  Is there anything in the linked github account that specifies these packages will run on 2.7?  I didn't see anything specific, but didn't check them all.

Comment: what operating system?

Comment: an indication that it's 2.7 is https://forums.plex.tv/t/when-will-plex-media-server-shift-to-python-3/600689/20 // and the operating system I am developing on is Mac OS Catalina; and I am using the shipped python since it's 2.7 anyways.